# Username Available Check Using Laravel 5 in Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

Username available check in my register form if I am enter the username after loader.gif is loading but I am not getting the result for username available or not.. give me any suggestion

This is My Controller:

```
public function name()
{
    $username = Input::get('username');
    $users = DB::table('user')
               ->where('username', $username)
               ->first(); 
    if ( $users !== null )
    {
        return true;
    }
         return false;
         return view('test/username');
}
```

This is My Route:

```
Route::get('test/name', 'PageController@name');
```

This is My Blade Template Ajax:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#username").change(function(){
             $("#message").html("<img src='../images/loader.gif' /> checking...");


        var username=$("#username").val();
          //alert(username);
          $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                 dataType: "json",
                url :"{{URL::to('test/name') }}",
               data: {username: username},
                    success:function(data){
                    if(data==0){
                        $("#message").html("<img src='../images/yes.png' /> Username available");
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#message").html("<img src='cross.png' /> Username already taken");
                    }
                }
             });

        });

     });
```

Comment: Please see the console and you able to ajax process

Comment: i have seen console i am getting 500 internal server error...

Comment: can you please update your question with 500 internal server error description

Comment: hi solve this problem for 500 internal server error.. but i am not getting the username availbale or not.. now loader.gif  only loading.. in my console i am getting the whatever i enter the name is coming like  http://localhost/laravel-test/public/test/username?username=murali

Comment: Sorry I'm not getting you

Comment: I am sorry ,,, Now my ajax is working fine, whenever I am entering any name i am able to see ajax request whatever I have entered, But it's not returning any results after comparing from DB

Comment: your code is perfect. see the AJAX Response.

Comment: ajax is not response to the controller this is my problem

Answer (score 1):

> ajax is not response to the controller this is my problem

This is because you need to send `json` using the `response()` method from the controller to your view file.

Try out this way:

Controller:

```
public function name(Request $request)
{
    // your validation logic ..

    $userFound = User::find($request->input('username'))

    if($userFound !== null) {
        return response([
            'status'  => 'failed',
            'message' => 'User Not Found'
        ]);
    }

    return response([
        'status'  => 'success',
        'message' => 'User Found'
    ]);
}
```

And then update your `success` method of AJAX handler:

```
$.ajax({
    // ..

    success: function(receivedData) {
        console.log(receivedData);
    }

    // ..

});
```

Comment: thanks i tried your suggestion but it is not working

Comment: in my ajax not responding from controller  select the username from database... how to call controller in this php query like       $username=$_POST["username"];
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from user where username='$username' ");
 
  $find=mysql_num_rows($query);
 
  echo $find;